# Word describing that things become more difficult to understand rather than easier

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes that things become more difficult to understand rather than easier as a result of for instance someone's explanation for something. That is, the explanation *is supposed to be illuminating*, but has the opposite effect (i.e. it leaves you more puzzled instead).

e.g.: His explanation for that math problem was very ... I'm even more puzzled now!

Answer (score 3):

Try *convoluted*.

> **Convoluted** *adjective*
>   1 (Especially of an argument, story, or sentence) extremely complex and difficult to follow
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/convoluted)

Putting this into your sample sentence, we get:

> His explanation for that math problem was very convoluted. I'm even more puzzled now!

Comment: Thanks, this works in the sentence but what I'm really looking for is a word that conveys the fact that the explanation *is supposed to be illuminating*, but has the opposite effect (i.e. it leaves you more puzzled instead).

Comment: *Why* was it not illuminating? Was the other person inept; was the topic or explanation pitched at too high a level, etc?

Comment: Mostly that the explanation was simply inadequate. The defenition of the word I'm looking for would be something like: "attempting to make things easier to understand, but having the opposite effect".

Comment: @dreamer *Inadequate* because it's actually wrong, or *inadequate* because you didn't understand it?

Comment: Because the explanation is not good enough (and/or wrong).

Comment: @dreamer In that case, the word you came up with (i.e. *inadequate*) works.

Answer (score 2):

Is this answer fitting?

[**Obfuscate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obfuscation)

> To make so confused or opaque as to be difficult to perceive or understand:
>
> *"A great effort was made ... to obscure or obfuscate the truth"* (Robert Conquest).

Answer (score 1):

As in:

> His explanation for that math problem was very *befogging*. I'm even
>   more puzzled now!

**befog**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/befog)

> tr.v. befogged, befogging, befogs
>   1. To cover or obscure with or as if with fog.
>   2. To cause confusion in; muddle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***[sophisticated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sophisticated)***

> (Of a machine, system, or ***technique***) developed to a high degree of complexity

**Usage:**

> His explanation for that math problem was very ***sophisticated*** that I'm even more puzzled now!

If you are open to idiomatic phrases, then see my [earlier answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/311102/150645) to another question that might possibly fit into your context.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest [obtuse](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Obtuse) but apparently the word I mean is [**abstruse**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/abstruse).

From thefreedictionary.com [first entry from American Heritage](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Obtuse):

> Usage Note: Obtuse is sometimes used where one might expect abstruse instead, but the Usage Panel is divided on the acceptability of these usages. In our 2009 survey, 55 percent of the Usage Panel rejected obtuse meaning "recondite," as in The reader has to struggle through dense prose and obtuse references to modern philosophers. Some 52 percent rejected the word when used to mean "indirect or oblique" in the sentence Divorce is mentioned, and there are a few obtuse references to sex. By contrast, 56 percent accepted sentences in which obtuse was used to mean "hard to follow or understand" in the phrases obtuse instructions and obtuse explanation. Perhaps the use of the word as a sophisticated synonym of stupid makes these extended derogatory uses more tolerable than they otherwise might be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is ***counter-intuitive?***

Since something is most easily understandable if it is intuitive, a word that ends up doing the opposite (i.e. obfuscating instead of illuminating) is counter-intuitive.

Counter-intuitve is the word to use if you want to describe whether the meaning of a word is readily apparent or not from how the word is constructed, without saying making any judgments on its correctness.

Comment: No. OP asks about the 'explanation that makes matters worse', not an inherent property of the topic. 'Counter-productive' is closer, but only ballpark, not spot on.