# What word means something or someone that goes/works against itself?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think I remember a word like that and it begins with the prefix counter. Can anyone help me?

Comment: **Self-damaging**, *self-destructive*?

Comment: Counterintuitive.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word you are looking for is [*counterproductive*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/counterproductive):

> adjective
>
> 1.
> thwarting the achievement of an intended goal; tending to defeat one's purpose:

See also the answer to this question:

[Is there an English word or phrase that means “intending to help and hurting instead?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311099/is-there-an-english-word-or-phrase-that-means-intending-to-help-and-hurting-ins)

Comment: This doesn't imply working *against yourself* though. Counterproductive is just against something else.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: it doesn't rule out working against yourself either, and the OP did ask for a word beginning with 'counter' :-)

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps you've answered the question and I've answered the title. :)

Comment: I like *counterproductive* for what the OP described.  Include the definition, not just a link, and I'll upvote.  I think that's the way we're supposed to write answers here.

Comment: @aparente001: done - it would have been counterproductive not to :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want: *contradict*, as in  *contradictory*,  *contradiction*,  *contradicting*, *contradicted*, *contrary*, and so on.

It’s not *counter-*; it’s *contra-.* But the etymology is basically the same.

I also like: *paradox* and *oxymoron*, both of which I consider to be similar or at least somewhat related.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't start with *counter-*, I think *self-defeating* is worth considering.

Link: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/self-defeating