# Need a word/phrase/proverb for this situation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

The situation when an action is taken to make something better it turns out to more be actually more damaging than healing?

Comment: schlimmbesserung?

Comment: Answered at [Expression for intending to help but instead making things worse](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120681/expression-for-intend-to-help-but-instead-making-things-worse/120682#120682).

Comment: That will do! I think I missed out on searching more accurately

Comment: Also related: ‘[Expression that means something like “killing the sheep to keep them from being kidnapped”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43585)’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Throwing the baby out with the bathwater." While disposing of waste,(the dirty water) you inadvertently got rid of something valuable (the baby).

Answer (score 1):

[Exacerbate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exacerbate)?

> make (a problem, bad situation, or negative feeling) worse.

-ODO

Comment: Please do not copy and paste an answer without attribution.

Answer (score -1):

"Unintended consequences" - your action/intention had an unexpected, less desirable result

"Backfired" - your action/intention created a worse result

"Made matters worse" - your action/intention had a negative effect

Comment: You should include an explanation of why these phrases are good choices; otherwise the answer is not complete.