# What is a word that describes when you try to fix something bad but destroy something good in the process?

Tags: single-word-requests, irony

I am watching a video of a person releasing a mouse from a plastic trap into the "wild," but it was actually released in an open field. The freed mouse gets across the field and then a large bird happens upon it. Is there a word that describes "Hell is paved with good intentions?" Kind of ironic, but saying more than it merely backfired.

Comment: Is it the law of unintended consequences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expression for "intend to help but instead making things worse"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120681/expression-for-intend-to-help-but-instead-making-things-worse)

Comment: See also: [Is there an English word or phrase that means “intending to help and hurting instead?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311099/is-there-an-english-word-or-phrase-that-means-intending-to-help-and-hurting-ins?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Again..your title sounds like "_sacrifice_", but the text describes "_ironic_".  Those are 2 very different concepts. Do you need a word to encompass both?

Comment: Cascabel, please don't get snippy. It was unintended, but not a sacrifice. A sacrifice would imply it was intended. Ironic may be more suitable, but I was looking for a different word. Thanks.

Comment: Livresque, thanks for the link but they basically said what I've said here. It's not exactly what I am looking for. I will also look at your other link.

Comment: Well Livresque, everyone is saying the same thing: well-intentioned. I feel like there is a better phrase or word out there, besides irony or hindrance.

Comment: OK thanks everybody. I think I've seen enough answers. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This one is close to the "straightener for a bender" question (Italian proverb). German has a single vefb for this, btw. I would translate it ad-hoc as *dis-improve*, but that's not quite correct. Not much better: *to impose, protest, change one evil for another, fix a bug add hundred more.*

Comment: Collateral damage?

Comment: There is **no single word** that conveys the idea of helping someone or something and it backfiring or actually being more harmful. There are plenty of phrases and idioms but not one "word".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an English word or phrase that means "intending to help and hurting instead?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311099/is-there-an-english-word-or-phrase-that-means-intending-to-help-and-hurting-ins)

Comment: *"Hell is paved with good intentions?"* This is wrong. The saying is "***The road to** Hell is paved with good intentions*" (The general belief is that Hell itself is not paved as it is a lake of molten brimstone.)

Answer (score 1):

Situations as the one you are describing are  generally referred to as:

***[out of the frying pan into the fire](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/out-of-the-frying-pan-into-the-fire)***
(saying)

> when you move from a bad or difficult situation to one that is worse

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: When having lunch at the monastery it's "Out of the frying pan, into the friar."

Answer (score 1):

To throw the baby out with the bathwater.  [LINK](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+the+baby+out+with+the+bath+water)

> To discard something valuable or important while disposing of something considered worthless, especially an outdated idea or form of behavior.

Comment: I really don’t see how that applies to feeling good about freeing a mouse into the wild only to see it all go terribly wrong as a hawk snatches it up.

Answer (score 0):

Another phrase:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/going+from+bad+to+worse

*Going from bad to worse.*